# Selecting popular models based on count of has_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
Novel has_many :pages
Page belongs_to :novel
```

I want to list popular Novels according to page count.  Essentially, I want Novel models loaded from the outcome of this query:

```
select p.novel_id, count(*) as count
from pages p
GROUP BY p.novel_id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I'm sure there's some cute way to do it in Rails 2.3 using named_scope, but I can't quite get it to work.  Plus, if it does work, is it going to be dog slow?

I've considered keeping page_count on Novel, but that seems like a violation of something (convention, normalization, my soul).

Comment: The counter cache is one way to go on this, but it's a shame rails doesn't provide a way (at least that I've found) of duplicating this query in active record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like counter cache is the way to go. If you create a column called page_count on the novels table (with an index), Rails will cache the number of pages on the Novel model itself, making this kind of query very easy and performant.

The `named_scope` on the `Novel` model then becomes

```
class Novel < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :popular, :order => 'page_count desc'
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :novel, :counter_cache => true
end
```

For more details check out [the counter cache railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Comment: I went with this plan, and I wasn't aware that Rails provided :counter_cache for you.  It'll work for now.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's going to be pretty slow. It's not a horrible thing to cache the page_count in your Novel. Normalization is all well and good, until it impacts performance.

Caching expensive calculations is the essence of most optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a `counter_cache` on the Novel is deemed acceptable in this matter and should aid your query.

In *page.rb* do:

```
 belongs_to :novel, :counter_cache => true
```

And in your `novels` table put a `pages_count` column. This will be automatically incremented when you create pages and decremented when you remove them.